# Recomandation and help required for NEWS website

Tags: php, mysqli

I am recently working on a new website, the website is actually belongs to **NEWS** category.
First of all I need some help in PHP, cause I am new in php and learning methods of it.
On front page there is about 10 headlines are showing, I fetch the first 4 news by `while` loop like this :

```
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            $sqlHomeLatest1 = "SELECT * FROM story  WHERE catagory LIKE CONCAT('%' , 'HomeTop', '%') ORDER BY DandTStory DESC LIMIT 4";
            $resultHomeLatest1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlHomeLatest1);
            mysqli_query ($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
            while($rowHomeLatest1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultHomeLatest1)){}
```

Now I want to reorder in these 4 headline in loop is that possible to do ?
If yes then how can I do this?
secondly I want your ideas about NEWS portal side and also new techniques of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change your order by or you could store your results in an array variable and grab them in whatever order you want.

Comment: actually the categories are stored in comma separated then how can I explode and use them?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Normalise your database into many-to-many relationships. Learn about what the means. Storing comma separated data is not the way to use a database. Then sort in the database. For your other "ideas" question, we can't help you there.